# Nagios warning and critical notifications interval

Tags: notifications, monitoring, nagios

I'm trying to configure Nagios service notifications this way:

- Send email notification after being for 30 minutes in the warning state
- Send email notification after being for 15 minutes in the critical state

I can't get it working at all. I can' manage the situation when there is a warning for a short time followed by the critical (or vice versa). Nagios seems to combine time spent in these states together, which is not what I want.

Do you have some ideas how to get it working as expected?

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things depending on what you want, but be aware that nagios is not timebased, but number of checks based.

1. Use max_check_attempts and check_interval:

You can set the maximum amount of checks before it sends an alerts (based on the check interval). example: check every 5  minutes; max_check_attempts: 4; on the 15th minute it will send an alert if after 4  checks in a row it is in critical or warning.

2. use escalation

You can use nagios escalation, this is defined in their documentation here:

http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/nagioscore/4/en/objectdefinitions.html#serviceescalation

What you can do it set a certain check period and say that between check 1-5 it is a warning and between check 6-10 it is a critical if it is not fixed in the mean time.